# Is file and if directory checks in nushell

Tags: nushell

What is the `nushell` equivalent to following bash.

```
if [[ -d $LOCATION ]]; then

elif [[ -f $LOCATION ]]; then

fi
```

Comment: Do you really want the auto-split and auto-glob of unquoted variables in a POSIX shell there?

Comment: @thrig, it won't get split within `[[ .. ]]`.

Comment: how unexpectedly irregular!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I'm missing a more functional way of doing this, but:

```
if ($LOCATION | path type) == "file" {
    echo "It's a file." 
} else if ($LOCATION | path type) == "dir" {
    echo "It's a directory"
}
```